# Fire event when the textbox changes in Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I'm using `EditForm` and `InputText` to achieve data binding and forms validation. (Using `<input @bind="SomeProperty" />` doesn't seem to fire component validation.)

I want to attach an event handler that gets fired whenever the value of the textbox changes:

```
<InputText @bind-Value="@model.ZipCode" @onkeypress="@model.InvokeThisMethod)"></InputText>
```

This sort of works, but when I'm in the event handler it's apparently firing before `ZipCode` has updated. The goal here is to do a thing when the zip code reaches 5 characters, not when the text input loses focus. I've also tried just forcing the change event to fire `oninput` but that just creates an error on the console about ChangedEventArgs to string not working.

How can I fire an event after the input field has updated the data binding?

Answer (score 1):

```
<InputText class="form-control" Value="@model.ZipCode" ValueExpression="@( ()=> model.ZipCode )" ValueChanged="@( (string s) => model.InvokeThisMethod(s) )"></InputText>
```

I didn't find this in the Microsoft documentation. I found it on the Telerik site for their Blazor controls (which apparently works for the non Telerik controls).

Dealing with form fields in Blazor really sucks right now.

```
<input @bind="model.Property" />
```

or

```
<InputText @bind-Value="model.Property" />
```

and then the `ValueExpression` attributes shown above. The intellisense in .razor files for VS2019 is poorly implemented. This sucks.

Comment: If value binding were the first executed event in a textbox, that would make life a lot easier on these controls. That way, any keypresses would re-bind the control FIRST and you would be able to get the value out. Another thing would be to have a default button (so when you press ENTER key, the "default"  button fires the event - .Net 7 and we still don't have defaultable buttons). If you trap the onkeydown event, you can't see the current values of any textbox, since their binding events don't fire - need a button for that.

Comment: I gave up on Blazer. Doing React with TypeScript now and a lot happier.

Comment: I think I'll do some research on raw WASM. Both Blazor and Rust have shortcomings regarding their high-level language implementations. WASM is too fast for me to ignore (I'm writing real-time monitoring stuff for lab equipment that works directly with websockets via WASM - even optimized javascript, being interpreted, isn't fast enough as the data needs to be heavily pre-processed before display). We need another implementation that uses MS libraries, just not Blazor, proper.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything under the sun to get the grid to reload via the search string after inserting a new record, and failing, I found that I can just reload the grid by setting the search string to empty and displaying all the results (simply having a value in the search box prevents the grid from refreshing after an insert - there is no solution I could get to work for this), but at least it shows the record as being inserted.  While this isn't the answer I was looking for, it will suffice for now.

Here's the index.razor page (final):

```
    @page "/"
@inject IConfiguration config
@inject DialogService dialog
@inject NotificationService notification

<PageTitle>Memo Master</PageTitle>
<RadzenButton Click="() => GetMemos()" Text="Get Memos" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" />
<RadzenTextBox @ref="searchBox" Name="SearchPhrase" @bind-Value="@SearchString" MaxLength="400" @oninput="@(args => SearchString = args.Value?.ToString())" @onkeydown="@Enter" />
<RadzenButton Click="() => OpenMemo(0)" Text="New Memo" Icon="add_circle_outline" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" />
<br />
<br />
@if (FoundMemos != null && !busy)
{
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref=this.grid Data="@FoundMemos" TItem="MemoSearch" AllowFiltering="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnResize="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize=20
                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" SelectionMode="DataGridSelectionMode.Single" @bind-Value="@SelectedMemos" RowClick="@OnRowClicked">
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="MemoSearch" Title="Index" Width="70px" Filterable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left">
                <Template Context="m">
                    <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Caption">@m.Idx.ToString()</RadzenText>
                </Template>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="MemoSearch" Property="Title" Title="Title">
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="MemoSearch" Title="Modified" Width="140px" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right">
                <Template Context="m">
                    <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Caption">@m.ModifiedOn.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")</RadzenText>
                </Template>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
}
else
{
    <DisplaySpinner />
}
<br />
<br />
<RadzenButton Click="Reset" Text="Reset" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" />


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? SearchString { get; set; }
    List<MemoSearch> FoundMemos = new();
    private string DBConnStr { get; set; } = "";
    public DB dB = new();
    IList<MemoSearch>? SelectedMemos;
    RadzenTextBox? searchBox;
    private bool busy;
    private RadzenDataGrid<MemoSearch>? grid; //reference to grid, so forced reloading can happen - though it doesn't actually work

    async Task OpenMemo(int Idx)
    {
        string DialogTitle = (Idx == 0) ? "Create New Memo" : $"Edit Memo {Idx.xToStr()}";
        object? RefreshResults = await dialog.OpenAsync<MemoDetails>(DialogTitle, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Idx", Idx } });
        RefreshResults = (RefreshResults == null) ? false : RefreshResults;
        if (RefreshResults.xToBoo())
        {
            if (Idx == 0) SearchString = ""; //force setting to empty reloads grid but only w/o search entry
            await GetMemos();
        }
        await ReturnFocus();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        dB.DBConnStr = await Task<string>.Run(()=> config.GetConnectionString("DBConnStr"));
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) await ReturnFocus();  //NOTE: this is for Radzen "elements"
    }

    public async Task GetMemos()
    {
        busy = true;
        FoundMemos = await dB.MemoSearchByPageFilterSortAsync(SearchString, PageSize: 9999);
        busy = false;
    }

    public async Task Reset()
    {
        FoundMemos = new();
        SearchString = "";
        await ReturnFocus();
    }

    public async void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter" || e.Key == "Enter")
        {
            await GetMemos();
            StateHasChanged(); //need to call this here after keypress, lest you get a continual spinner
        }
    }

    async Task OnRowClicked(Radzen.DataGridRowMouseEventArgs<MemoSearch> args)
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            await OpenMemo(args.Data.Idx);
        }
    }

    async Task ReturnFocus()
    {
        if (searchBox != null) await searchBox.Element.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

and the MemoDetails.razor page:

```
    @inject IConfiguration config
@inject DialogService dialog
@inject NotificationService notification

@if (memo != null)
{
    <RadzenTemplateForm TItem="Memo" Data=@memo Submit=@OnSubmit>
        <p>
            <RadzenLabel Component="Title" Text="Title" />
            <RadzenTextBox id="MemoTitle" Name="Title" @bind-Value=@memo.Title MaxLength="400" />
            <RadzenRequiredValidator Component="Title" Text="Title is required!" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <RadzenLabel Component="Body" Text="Memo" />
            <RadzenTextArea id="MemoBody" Name="Body" @bind-Value=@memo.Body Rows="18" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <RadzenLabel Component="Keywords" Text="Key Words" />
            <RadzenTextBox id="MemoKeywords" Name="Keywords" @bind-Value=@memo.Keywords MaxLength="400" />
        </p>
        <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Success" Icon="save" Text="Save" BusyText="Saving ..." IsBusy=@busy />
        @if (Idx > 0)
        {
            <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Text="Delete" Click="@((args) => DeleteMemo(memo.Idx))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true"></RadzenButton>
        }
        <RadzenButton Text="Close" Click="() => dialog.Close(false)" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" />
    </RadzenTemplateForm>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Idx { get; set; } = 0;

    public DB dB = new();
    Memo? memo;
    bool busy;

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        dB.DBConnStr = config.GetConnectionString("DBConnStr");
        memo = (Idx == 0) ? new Memo() : await GetMemoByIdx(Idx);
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()).ConfigureAwait(false); //IMPORTANT!!
    }

    public async Task<Memo> GetMemoByIdx(int Idx) => await dB.MemoSelectByIdxAsync(Idx);

    async Task OnSubmit(Memo memo)
    {
        int Result;
        bool RefreshResults = false;
        if (memo.ModifiedOn == DateTime.MinValue) memo.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        string NotificationDetailMessage = memo.Idx == 0 ? "New Memo has been created." : $"Memo {memo.Idx} has been saved.";
        busy = true;
        Result = await dB.MemoUpsertAsync(memo);
        if (Result < -1)
        {
            notification.Notify(new NotificationMessage { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error, Summary = "Error Saving", Detail = "An error saving this record has occured!\n" + dB.LastErrorMsg, Duration = 4000 });
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Notify(new NotificationMessage { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Success, Summary = "Save Success", Detail = NotificationDetailMessage, Duration = 2000 });
            RefreshResults = true;
        }
        busy = false;
        dialog.Close(RefreshResults);
    }

    async Task DeleteMemo(int Idx)
    {  
        int Result;
        bool RefreshResults = false;
        var confirmResult = await dialog.Confirm("Are you sure?", "Confirm Memo Deletion");
        if (confirmResult.HasValue && confirmResult.Value)
        {
            busy = true;
            Result = await dB.MemoDeleteByIdxAsync(Idx);
            if (Result < -1)
            {
                notification.Notify(new NotificationMessage { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error, Summary = "Error Deleting", Detail = "An error deleting this record has occured!\n" + dB.LastErrorMsg, Duration = 4000 });
            }
            else
            {
                notification.Notify(new NotificationMessage { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Success, Summary = "Deletion Success", Detail = $"Memo {Idx} has been deleted.", Duration = 2000 });
                RefreshResults = true;
            }
        }
        busy = false;
        dialog.Close(RefreshResults);
    }

}
```

Good enough, for now, but still baffled as to what Radzen is doing behind the scenes.